# Config file Error to start Nagios service

Tags: nagios

When I uncomment `nagios.cfg` I have a problem to start Nagios service.

Job for `nagios.service` failed because the control process exited with error code. See `systemctl status nagios.service` and `journalctl -xe` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to validate your Nagios configuration (with the correct paths, of course). It'll point you to where the error is in the nagios.cfg.

```
/opt/nagios/bin/nagios -v /opt/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Comment: This is the problem :  Could not open config directory '/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/hosts.cfg' for reading.
Error: Invalid max_check_attempts value for host 'host unix'
Error: Could not register host (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg', starting on line 31)
   Error processing object config files!

Comment: It's telling you exactly where to look for the problem. What is max_check_attempts value for host 'host unix' set to? You need to post some of your configuration, starting with line 31.